# X doesn't start after Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, xorg, fglrx

I'm trying to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.

I was making the upgrade over the X session of 11.10 i386. I was in the middle of the instalation when the X freezed. So i've made a reboot. When it restarted, i was already in 12.04 version but with the black screen problem. So i've added nomodeset to grub options.

I've runned the commands:

`sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

in order to install the missing packages (because of the X freeze).
In total the commands installed/upgraded about 1GB more.

But no X yet. So i've uninstalled the fglrx packages and tried to install the amd ati (vendor) package. It give some errors (compilation errors) so i've cleaned it up and reinstalled the fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle ubuntu packages.

CURRENT PROBLEM:
No X, yet.

When i run the command:

`apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`

a strange output happens (related to link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf):

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/45.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 129 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
[...]
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 483649 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx (from .../fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up fglrx (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-8.960 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Done.

fglrx:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

But it seems to install correctly and compiled all the modules to the current kernel.

`runned the commmand: aticonfig --initial -f`

`After reboot, still no X .`

I tried to run the X with no fglrx drivers and with. I spend a lot of time on this problem and i really wonder if i can solve it widthout reinstalling ubuntu from scratch.

Other info:

`uname -a`

```
Linux  [name] 3.2.0-24.generic-pae #37-ubuntu  SMP Wed Apr 25 10:47:59 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i368
```

`lspci`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]
```

`Xorg.0.log`

```
[    24.741] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    24.741] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    24.741] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-23-generic i686 Ubuntu
[    24.741] Current Operating System: Linux beatsaudio 3.2.0-24-generic-pae #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 10:47:59 UTC 2012 i686
[    24.741] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=dab0cc0d-adaa-4a14-a633-b2f9841935ff ro quiet splash nomodeset vt.handoff=7
[    24.741] Build Date: 20 April 2012  05:12:21AM

[.....]

[    28.283] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x37) [0xb7724627]
[    28.283] 1: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x18c3aa) [0xb77283aa]
[    28.283] 2: (vdso) (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0) [0xb757940c]
[    28.283] 3: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb71d9000+0x135d32) [0xb730ed32]
[    28.283] 4: /usr/bin/X (XIChangeDeviceProperty+0x16c) [0xb76bcafc]
[    28.283] 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0xb4a25000+0x634e) [0xb4a2b34e]
[    28.283] 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0xb4a25000+0x6595) [0xb4a2b595]
[    28.283] 7: /usr/bin/X (ActivateDevice+0x66) [0xb75c82e6]
[    28.284] 8: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x8cc05) [0xb7628c05]
[    28.284] 9: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x9b142) [0xb7637142]
[    28.284] 10: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x9b9b3) [0xb76379b3]
[    28.284] 11: /usr/bin/X (config_init+0x14) [0xb7636a14]
[    28.284] 12: /usr/bin/X (InitInput+0xfd) [0xb7616edd]
[    28.284] 13: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x2524e) [0xb75c124e]
[    28.284] 14: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0xb71f24d3]
[    28.284] 15: /usr/bin/X (0xb759c000+0x255e9) [0xb75c15e9]
[    28.284] Segmentation fault at address 0xf3
[    28.284] 
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    28.284] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at 
 for help. 
[    28.284] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    28.284] 
[    28.288] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[    28.288] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    28.288] (II) Unloading evdev
[    28.292] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[    28.292] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    28.292] (II) Unloading evdev
[    28.308] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[    28.308] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    28.308] (II) Unloading evdev
[    28.312] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[    28.312] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    28.312] (II) Unloading evdev
[    28.312] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    28.312] (II) Unloading evdev
[    28.664]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[    28.664] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found out the problem. Follow this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969827

Comment: I had to reinstall X first...