# Freeze after startup

Tags: startup, freeze

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. At first it worked just fine, but when i started updating the system just "updated" the screen, and then freezed. Same thing happens when I log in. Any tip?

Comment: I had a similar problem. My machine has a 'hybrid' Intel / AMD graphics setup. If you have the same, you may find you installed the AMD driver when updating your system. When the AMD driver is installed, the screen 'freezes' after you log in. To fix it, I followed the instructions in post 107 on the following thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=11

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problem when updated to 12.04.

What i've done was in a console ( ctr + alt + f1 ) to uninstall the packages xserver-xorg, ubuntu-desktop (and fglrx packages because i have an ati)

To uninstall:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg ubuntu-desktop`

After doing this you may have uninstalled some usufull packages like gnome. Before uninstall check the packages that apt-get uninstalled to manually do that when you reinstall again the packages.

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg ubuntu-desktop`

--------- [init] DO YOU HAVE AN ATI?----------------

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*`

Then try to install your graphic card drivers property. If you have an ati:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx 
(download it before you uninstall these packages)

I also recommend do check this post: [X doesn't start after Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130399/x-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

--------- [END] DO YOU HAVE AN ATI?----------------

Before you try this you can also try to run the command:

`apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg ubuntu-desktop`

Good luck.