# Lightdm won't start Unity automatically

Tags: unity, lightdm

The problem I have is that after I have entered my username and password, all I get is a blank desktop. No launcher and I am unable to click anything.

After some googling around, I switch to a console (Alt-F1) and run unity --replace. I then switch back to X console, and unity is running fine, and I can confirm it is unity-3d that is running (I am typing this from one of these manual sessions).

So, in desperation, I tried to install gdm instead. gdm seems to work, i.e. after login I get my desktop with launcher, but it is unity-2d and not unity-3d - even though the session is ubuntu and not ubuntu 2d.

So, how do I go about getting lightdm to automatically start unity-3d properly?

Some further info: If I switch to the discrete graphics card in Catalyst Control Centre, then the problem goes away (but my battery life drops drastically, and fans spin continuously).

I am not sure what info you need to help me out...

All I can tell you is that I have a laptop with switchable graphics. The 'onboard' graphics is an Intel HD3000 and the 'discrete' is a Radeon 6770M. I use the Onboard graphics (set via Catalyst Control Centre) as it eats a lot less battery.

Comment: Some further info: If I switch to the discrete graphics card in Catalyst Control Centre, then the problem goes away (but my battery life drops drastically, and fans spin continuously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Hi, thanks... I've tried that, but it does not seem to have helped

Comment: See my answer to this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139484/freeze-after-startup/139500#139500   . When this happen i had to make this but not only because of what your are happening to you. If you have time, and you know what you are doing, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it, so I thought I'd post here in case anyone else has a similar issue. The solution can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=11 (Post 107)

Essentially, you need to change the /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10fglrx file to include the path for the intel drivers in the LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH variable. Once I did this, Unity3d runs without issue.